# CoreData pre-supply app with sqlite

Tags: cocoa

how can i provide a filled sqlite database in advance

like i would have an app. with a database already containing items, not just download the data at the first start

i can replace the sqlite with the one in use, but i don't know how to create the sqlite file

```
-(void)importDatabaseToDocumentsDir
{
    NSFileManager *fmngr = [[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSString *filePath = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Kalkulacka.sqlite" ofType:nil];
    NSError *error;
    if(filePath != nil && ![fmngr copyItemAtPath:filePath toPath:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@/Documents/%@", NSHomeDirectory(),@"Kalkulacka.sqlite"] error:&error]) {
        // handle the error
        //NSLog(@"Error creating the database: %@", [error description]);

    }
    [fmngr release];
}
```

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The obvious ways would be to either…

a) use your app, creating the data you want and save and copy the resulting file or

b) add a second target of type "Command Line Tool" to your Xcode project which includes the classes that relate to your data-model and allows you to populate and save the populated data-file.

Comment: the solution was to fill the database : export all data from the device (using organizer), renaming the exported data to zip, so i can traverse it and find the sqlite... then import it as mentioned